# How to use PHP to get the website bandwidth

Tags: php, server, bandwidth

I want to get the website bandwidth with PHP

get the information like this:
aaa.example.com  200g/m
bbb.example.com  150g/m

Comment: we have to see what you have done first, and then take it from there....

Comment: hi utility I tried piwik's plugin bandwidth, but not working.
I want to get every sub domain flow bandwidth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think PHP have any standard tools to provide this data. You probably will have to set up custom logs for Apache where it will save subdomain and page size for all requests and then you will need to extract this data and present it with some statistical tool like Munin. Actually maybe someone already made a plugin for Munin that is doing just that, just try to google for it.